# Cannot see application folder in Android/data while installing with flutter

Tags: file, flutter, android-emulator

```
Future get _localPath async {
final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
return directory.path;
}

Future _createDirectory() async {
final String path = await _localPath;
final Directory directory = await Directory('$path/CapturedImages').create(recursive: true);
print("The directory $directory is created");
}
```

D/EGL_emulation(14006): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeaff6780: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc942c8e0)
I/flutter (14006): The directory Directory: '/data/user/0/quadauq.ffmpeg_examplebyneena/app_flutter/CapturedImages' is created
D/EGL_emulation(14006): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeafc6d40: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xdf9af9b0)

Showing as a success, but I cannot see application folder or the created folder anywhere in Andrid/data - can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can request the storage directory:

```
Future get _localPath async {
  final Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}
```

instead of the app documents directory.

So, you can see application the created folder in `Android/data/quadauq.ffmpeg_examplebyneena/files/CapturedImages`

Comment: sorry I meant in the emulator, I cannot see package folder in Android/data

Comment: Even after installation on Android device i do not see the app directory when look at manually. When analizing the package it's look like should be ``/data/app/<packagename>`` but still not found it

Comment: Ok, it's look like Flutter applications do not create their own application-specific folders in Internal Storage, if you want that you have to use **path_provider** package https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider